# Query Oracle database from Cloud Foundry using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cloud-foundry

I have a Python web app that needs to query an Oracle database.

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_string)
print (conn.version)
```

To do that, I currently use cx_Oracle driver and it works great locally.

Unfortunately, when I deploy the app, I can't get it to work because the driver is missing. I tried, among other things, to put the driver in a modules directory.

I was wondering if there was a way to query an Oracle database from Cloud Foundry (I am not particularly attached to cx_oracle if there is an alternative way to query that works in Cloud Foundry).

To deploy, I have cx_oracle in a requirements file:

```
cx_Oracle
```

I also have a ProcFile

```
web: python web_main.py
```

This is the deployment log :

```
Updating app my-app...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 2.39 MiB / 2.39 MiB [======================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 3s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404

Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404

Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404

Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404

Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404

Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - can the driver be installed from a `requirements.txt`, or vendored per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring, for example? Is the database accessed via a service binding? What's the error?

Comment: I did not initially include source code because it is more about getting the library to work than connecting. Though I don't think it makes a difference, I included code/logs. Service binding does not make a difference because it is only about helping with the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

What is the CF CLI version you using?.
You have to use the CF CLI version which is lesser than v6.50.0 if you have not deployed Log cache on your CF platform.

Comment: @Youn Elan did you try with the lower version of CF CLI?